# Thinkpad T520 slow WiFi

Tags: wireless

Lately my Ubuntu WiFi is really slow. I upgraded to 11.10 but I already was experiencing slow WiFi in 11.04.

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"thename"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:1E:E5:64:AF:75   
          Bit Rate=135 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-30 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:569  Invalid misc:45   Missed beacon:0
```

After googling I also added the following

```
#disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

to the etc/sysctl.conf file and restarted my system but it's still slow.

I found a command to show all the specs of my PC and pasted it here:

http://pastebin.com/jrYhZUYj

If I need to provide additional information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switch my router to from mixed to bg-mixed and it seems to be okay again. Not really know what all the WiFi modes mean but it seems to work.

Comment: Modes are just newer (or older) standards, from oldest to newest, also slowest to fastest: B,G,N